# Regex date time matching

Tags: c#, regex, date

I am using C#

```
string content = " 4 marco bob 53 AUSTRIA (Jan. 13, 2012) – McDonald Janruary 15, 2021 July 15, 2923   June 2 2343 7/25/23 08/22/3323";
```

This should recognice all the dates except "4 marco bob 53" which is obviously not a datetime. However, my rules(below) match it(4 marco bob 53) and I cannot figure out how to avoid matching that(or similar examples).

I am trying to match the string above for all the date times. I wrote 3 rules to match some common date patterns.

eg:

Pattern f0: 5/2/2012

Pattern f2: 3 March 1900 or 3 Mar 1990 or 3 MAR. 1990 etc...

Pattern f3: Jan. 4, 2021 or January 4 2021, etc...

```
 string f0 = "([0-9]{1,2})/([0-9]{1,2})/([0-9]{2,4})";
 string f1 = "([0-9]{1,2})\\s+([jJ][aA][nN].*?|[fF][eE][bB].*?|[mM][aA][rR].*?|[aA][pP][rR].*?|[mM][aA][yY].*?|[jJ][uU][nN].*?|[jJ][uU][lL].*?|[aA][uU][gG].*?|[sS][eE][pP].*?|[oO][cC][tT].*?|[nN][oO][vV[.*?|[dD][eE][cC].*?)\\s+([0-9]{2,4})";
 string f2 = "([jJ][aA][nN].*?|[fF][eE][bB].*?|[mM][aA][rR].*?|[aA][pP][rR].*?|[mM][aA][yY].*?|[jJ][uU][nN].*?|[jJ][uU][lL].*?|[aA][uU][gG].*?|[sS][eE][pP].*?|[oO][cC][tT].*?|[nN][oO][vV[.*?|[dD][eE][cC].*?)\\s+([0-9]{1,2})[\\s,]+([0-9]{2,4})";
```

I am new to regex, so I am sure I am doing some silly stuff(like not using case insensitive options etc), so let me know how i can improve this as well.

This is for learning regex, not learning how to use library functions....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aggregated some of the answers posted to do what I wanted. This seems to be finding dates in free text reasonably well. Thanks to all posters.

```
string f0 = "(?:(\\d{1,2})/(\\d{1,2})/(\\d{2,4}))";
string f1 = "(?:(\\s\\d{1,2})\\s+(jan(?:uary){0,1}\\.{0,1}|feb(?:ruary){0,1}\\.{0,1}|mar(?:ch){0,1}\\.{0,1}|apr(?:il){0,1}\\.{0,1}|may\\.{0,1}|jun(?:e){0,1}\\.{0,1}|jul(?:y){0,1}\\.{0,1}|aug(?:ust){0,1}\\.{0,1}|sep(?:tember){0,1}\\.{0,1}|oct(?:ober){0,1}\\.{0,1}|nov(?:ember){0,1}\\.{0,1}|dec(?:ember){0,1}\\.{0,1})\\s+(\\d{2,4}))";
 string f2 = "(?:(jan(?:uary){0,1}\\.{0,1}|feb(?:ruary){0,1}\\.{0,1}|mar(?:ch){0,1}\\.{0,1}|apr(?:il){0,1}\\.{0,1}|may\\.{0,1}|jun(?:e){0,1}\\.{0,1}|jul(?:y){0,1}\\.{0,1}|aug(?:ust){0,1}\\.{0,1}|sep(?:tember){0,1}\\.{0,1}|oct(?:ober){0,1}\\.{0,1}|nov(?:ember){0,1}\\.{0,1}|dec(?:ember){0,1}\\.{0,1})\\s+([0-9]{1,2})[\\s,]+(\\d{2,4}))";

MatchCollection mc = Regex.Matches(content, f0 + "|" + f1 + "|" + f2, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your regex matches string f1 for the following reasons:

- `4` because of `([0-9]{1,2})\\s+`
- `mar` because of `[mM][aA][rR]`
- `co bob` because of `.*?`
- `53` because of `\\s+([0-9]{2,4}`

Remove your `.*?` that you have after each month. It means match *any* character in a non  greedy way. So what this does is it checks what your next condition is in your case `\\s+([0-9]{2,4}` so you match

Answer (score 2):

Addressing the named-month-pattern only: this combines 2 and 3, and would require one more step to fix the last match here: `89 Febuary 12, 2099`, but could be separated up pretty easily if you wish to do it that way:

```
    string input = " 4 marco bob 53 AUSTRIA (Jan. 13, 2012) – McDonald January 15, 2021 July 15, 2923   June 2 2343 7/25/23 08/22/3323 7 jul 2098 0 Jan 0 fake stuff 89 Febuary 12, 2099 it is a greedy";
    var pattern =
    @"(\d\d?\s)? (?# greedily gather preceding dd)
    (jan(uary)?|feb(uary)?|mar(ch)?|apr(il)?|may|june?|july?|aug(ust)?|sep(tember)?|nov(ember)?|dec(ember)?)
    \.?\s?                
    (\d\d?\b,?\s*)? (?# optional day part)
    \d\d(\d\d)?";           

    var matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
    string result = string.Empty;
    for (int i = 0; i < matches.Count; i++)
    {
        result += "match " + i + ",value:" + matches[i].Value + "\n";
    }   
    Console.WriteLine(result);
```

*edit: non backtracking was not necessary (remnant of more complicated look-ahead approach)-removed that part.*

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify which language you are doing this in.

Generally most languages will offer a method of parsing for dates, so using regex for validation yourself is not the answer.

Comment: Specify which language you are trying to learn regex in and I shall revise my answer.

Comment: I did...Also, I don't know of any C# methods to parse all date times out of a text document(eg free text).